# If Dataflow Job failed I want to update the database table column to record the fail status

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When one Pipeline finished and if the status is a failure, I want to update the database table column to record the failed status.

```
PipelineResult result = p.run();

IInternationalIngestionDb db = InternationalDbConnection.getInternationalIngestionDb(options.getDbConfigFile().get(),options.getDbName().get());
boolean upd = db.ingestionRequests().find(Long.parseLong("11091")).setErrorCode(-88888).save();

result.waitUntilFinish();
```

I want to use the above testing code to update database. But it didn't work.
Could someone have some opinions?

Comment: Can I add the update function in the Dataflow Job? Or, I should use some GCP functions like Cloud Functions?

Comment: This looks like a good article ... https://medium.com/@vallerylancey/error-handling-elements-in-apache-beam-pipelines-fffdea91af2a